# How to add a shadow to an SVG element

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have such an element made in SVG:

```
import Svg, { Path, Circle } from "react-native-svg"

function CloseIcon(props) {

    return (
        <Svg
            viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
            fillRule="evenodd"
            clipRule="evenodd"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            strokeMiterlimit={2}
            style={styles.shadow}
        >
            <Path
                d="M500 420.886L781.42 139.464c19.297-19.28 50.622-19.28 69.919 0l9.179 9.195c19.296 19.28 19.296 50.623 0 69.903L579.097 499.983l281.438 281.455c19.296 19.28 19.296 50.622 0 69.902l-9.179 9.195c-19.296 19.28-50.622 19.28-69.918 0L500 579.081 218.562 860.535c-19.297 19.28-50.623 19.28-69.919 0l-9.179-9.195c-19.296-19.28-19.296-50.622 0-69.902l281.438-281.455-281.421-281.421c-19.297-19.28-19.297-50.623 0-69.903l9.178-9.195c19.297-19.28 50.623-19.28 69.92 0l281.42 281.422z"
                fill="#fff"
            />
        </Svg>
    )
};
```

Is it possible to add a shadow to it?

These types of options do not work: (this solution treats the path as a rectangle)

```
shadowColor: "#000",
shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 2,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.23,
shadowRadius: 2.62,
elevation: 4,
```

Comment: You can use borderRadius in order to change the shape of the shadow.